# Miniconda path changes are not reflected inside tmux

Tags: python, tmux, miniconda

This is totally weird. I have installed miniconda and the PATH is set to my miniconda/bin directory. When I am inside `tmux`

```
(base) pradeepbanavara@Pradeeps-MacBook-Pro aerospike-kubernetes % echo $PATH
/Users/pradeepbanavara/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/pradeepbanavara/miniconda3/bin:/Users/pradeepbanavara/miniconda3/condabin:/Users/pradeepbanavara/.cargo/bin
```

Now `vhich python` gives me

```
(base) pradeepbanavara@Pradeeps-MacBook-Pro aerospike-kubernetes % which python
/usr/bin/python
```

and not
`/Users/pradeepbanavara/miniconda3/bin/python`

However `which pip` gives

```
(base) pradeepbanavara@Pradeeps-MacBook-Pro aerospike-kubernetes % which pip
/Users/pradeepbanavara/miniconda3/bin/pip
```

I've been scratching my head as to how on earth this can happen. One reason is because `/usr/bin` is before `/Users/pradeepbanavara/miniconda3/bin/python` in the PATH but shouldn't that impact `pip` also ?

If I get out of `tmux` the `python` and `pip` paths are the same.

Can someone please give me pointers on where to start debugging this ?

Comment: try `conda activate env` where `env` is name of your environment, after you have started tmux.

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't think it's the issue of Conda environments. Something between the interplay of tmux and Conda is not sitting right.